# mlflow runs folder properly mounted when dockerized

Tags: r, docker, docker-compose, mlflow

For my experimentation with mlflow I'm trying to dockerize R and mlflow with this docker compose configuration:

```
version: "3"

services:
  ui:
    image: ghcr.io/mlflow/mlflow:v2.4.0
    command: mlflow server -h 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    # problematic
    volumes:
      - "runs:/mlruns"

  rapp:
    image: mlflow-r
    build: .
    environment:
      - MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=http://ui:5000
      - DISABLE_AUTH=true
    volumes:
      - "./R:/home/rstudio/workspace"
    ports:
      - "8787:8787"

volumes:
  runs:
```

When the stack is up I run an R script from RStudio (the rapp service.)

If I run the stack without volumes it works fine. But when I try to add volumes (marked as '# problematic' above) mlflow complains: "Error: API request to endpoint 'runs/create' failed with error code 404. Reponse body: 'RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST; Could not find experiment with ID 0'". So I'm wondering if I'm mounting the volume correctly.

I'm also not able to mount the mlruns directory to my host directory.

What is the proper way of mounting mlruns directory as a volume?